# Electromagnetic wave within medium (penetration depth)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

> $E(x,t)=E_0e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ , $B(x,t)=B_0e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$
>
> The wave falls perpendicular onto a metal. Compute the penetration depth $\delta$, meaning the length within the metal at which the amplitude reduces to 1/e of its initial value. Let $k=\frac{\omega}{c}(\bar{n}+i\kappa)$ within the metal.

This is the last part of a problem set I've been dealing with. I can't seem to find a right approach to this. I was thinking of looking at the intensity to get the depth,

$I(x)=I_0e^{-\alpha \Delta x}$.

And from that setting $\frac{I(x)}{I_0}=1/e$ and from that to infer that $\Delta x=1/\alpha$. I assume that $\Delta x=\delta$? I got the formula from wikipedia when trying to search for penetration depth. Is that the right approach? And if so, what would $\alpha$ be in that case?

**Edit:** For some reason my original post got deleted so here it is again.

The person who answered my original post suggested to use maxwell's equation in combination with the current density from Ohm's law somehow to get to the solution but I couldn't get to the penetration depth. Although it might be that I tried using the wrong one of maxwell's equations.

Comment: Look it up in Griffith's Introduction to Electrodynamics; it may be indexed under skin depth.  Don't use the vacuum form of Maxwell's equations.  It is also covered in Jackson's Electrodynamics.

Comment: Why can you not use the complex k in your expression for E-field and obviously see that the penetration depth is $c/(\omega \kappa)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Maxwell's (local) equations in a linear, homogeneous, and isotropic medium read

$$\begin{align*}
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}&=0\\
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}&=0\\
\nabla\times\mathbf{E}&=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}\\
\nabla\times\mathbf{B}&=\mu\mathbf{J}+\mu\epsilon\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}
\end{align*}$$

Ohm's law tells us that the current density field $\mathbf{J}\approx \sigma \mathbf{E}$, where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the medium/material you're working with. If you take the curl of the third equation, and take Ohm's law as an equality, then you get

$$\nabla^2\mathbf{E}=\mu\epsilon\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{E}}{\partial t^2}+\mu\sigma\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

If you make an plane-wave solution ansatz, you can look for the required dispersion relation (i.e. frequency - wavelength relationship required to be a valid solution).

$$\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{E}_0e^{i(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}-\omega t)}$$

One way to do this is to set $\mathbf{k}=k\hat{z}$ and $\mathbf{E}_0=E_0\hat{x}$. It's worth mentioning that $\mathbf{E}$ being perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$ is a requirement by Maxwell's equations - namely, Gauss's law. By plugging this in, you will find that

$$k(\omega)=k_++ik_-,\,\,\,\, k_{\pm}=\omega\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon\mu}{2}}\sqrt{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon\omega}\right)}\pm 1}$$

The $k_-$ term, when plugged back into $\mathbf{E}$, will give rise to wave decay that behaves like $\exp [-k_-z]$. Thus, the penetration depth will simply be $\delta = 1/k_-$.